# Help required in query to show user specific jobs in which he is not applied or posted

Tags: sql-server-2012

[image: Schema]

this my schema of jobs and applied jobs I want to show jobs to a specific user which are not his jobs or in which he is not applied.

for example user 1 have job id 2,3,4 and applied in 7,8,9 query should get only jobs of 5 ,6 ,10

this is my  current query

[image: query]

but shows these result for user 4 but still job 3 and 18 are showing in which user is already applied
[image: results]

data in applied jobs table
[image: e]

Comment: Please read why you [should not post screenshots of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Please also consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   u.ID
   ,u.Name
   ,j.JOB_ID
   ,j.Title
   ,j.Descr
FROM
  Users u
LEFT JOIN Jobs j ON j.User_ID <> u.ID  
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT aj.Job_ID FROM Applied_Jobs aj WHERE aj.Job_ID = j.JOB_ID)
```

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b1d8877098288501c29001e8544933aa)

Comment: thanks for effort but i need jobs to show for specific users

Comment: You can always add tot the WHERE-clause  `AND u.ID=2` to only list user with ID=2 ?